# Square pyramidal numbers

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, arithmetic

[A000330 - OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000330)

## Task

Your task is simple, generate a sequence that, given index `i`, the value on that position is the sum of squares from `0` upto `i` where `i >= 0`.

## Example:

```
Input: 0
Output: 0           (0^2)

Input: 4
Output: 30          (0^2 + 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2)

Input: 5
Output: 55          (0^2 + 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2)
```

## Specification:

- You may take no input and output the sequence indefinitely;
- You may take input `N` and output the `Nth` element of the sequence;
- You may take input `N` and output the first `N` elements of the sequence.

Comment: Fun observation from OEIS: This sequence contains exactly two perfect squares: `f(1) == 1 * 1 (1)`, and `f(24) == 70 * 70 (4900)`.

Comment: May we begin the sequence at `f(1) = 1`?

Comment: @Emigna sorry but no, you need to start from `f(0) = 0`. i've pointed out that to the few answers that failed that requirement

Comment: The `f(0) = 0` requirement ruined a few of my solutions :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
R²S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/o0Kbg////mwAA)

FGITW

## Explanation

```
R²S  Main Link
R    Generate Range
 ²   Square (each term)
  S  Sum
```

Comment: A longer alternative would be `Ræ.R`

Answer (score 22):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 22 bytes

```python
lambda n:n*~n*~(n*2)/6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKk@rDog08rSMNPXN/qflFylkKmTmKRQl5qWnahgaaFpxKRQUZeaVKGTqKOnaKemkaWRq/gcA)

This uses the closed-form formula **n * (n+1) * (2*n+1) / 6**. The code performs the following operations:

- Multiplies **n** by (`n*`):

  - The bitwise complement of **n** (`~n`), which essentially means **-1-n**.
  - And by the bitwise complement of **2n** (`*~(n*2)`), which means **-1-2n**.
- Divides by **6** (`/6`).

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 27 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n and f(n-1)+n*n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEAXQfacYWmkpZEuh7mLY1EB9Rdx0@um9@vW7YFXl7UnvkRMhghIysYEPdsYE5dJISEAt4TpNWGwcqDZBJ3Gj30fHRqz@)

<sub>Saved 1 byte thanks to [Rod](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47120/rod) and 1 thanks to [G B](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/18535/g-b).</sub>

Comment: This is very clever!

Answer (score 14):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 3 bytes

```
:Us
```

... or them?

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3yq0@P9/EwA)

#### Explanation

```
:Us
:    % Implicit input n. Push range [1 2 ... n]
 U   % Square, element-wise
  s  % Sum of array. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 14):

## JavaScript (ES6), 16 bytes

```js
n=>n*(n+++n)*n/6
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

n=>n*(n+++n)*n/6

for(n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
  console.log('a(' + n + ') = ' + f(n))
}
```

#### How?

The expression `n+++n` is parsed as `n++ + n` <sup>(1)</sup>. Not that it really matters because `n + ++n` would also work in this case.

Therefore:

```js
n*(n+++n)*n/6 =
n * (n + (n + 1)) * (n + 1) / 6 =
n * (2 * n + 1) * (n + 1) / 6
```

which [evaluates to **sum(k=0...n)(k²)**](https://oeis.org/A000330).

---

*<sub>(1) This can be verified by doing `n='2';console.log(n+++n)` which gives the integer `5`, whereas `n + ++n` would give the string `'23'`.</sub>*

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
ÝnO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8Nw8////TQA)

**Explanation**

```
  O    # sum of
 n     # squares of
Ý      # range [0 ... input]
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 36 bytes

```
({<(({}[()])())>{({})({}[()])}{}}{})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6PaRkOjujZaQzNWU0NT064ayNGECdRW1wKR5v//pgA)

```
# Main algorithm
(                                  )  # Push the sum of:
                {({})({}[()])}{}      #   The square of:
 {                              }     #     0 to i 

# Stuff for the loop
  <(({}[()])())>                      # Push i-1, i without counting it in the sum
                                 {}   # Pop the counter (0)
```

Comment: Nicely done! :) I came up with `({<(({}))>{({})({}[()])}{}<({}[()])>})` for 38

Comment: [34 bytes ;)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145612/56656)

Answer (score 6):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 34 bytes

```
({(({}[()])()){({}[()])({})}{}}{})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6NaQ6O6NlpDM1ZTQ1OzGs6urtWsra4FIs3//00B)

## How does it work?

Initially I had the same idea as [Riley](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145553/56656)<sup>1</sup> but it felt wrong to use a zeroer.  I then realized that

```
{({}[()])({})}{}
```

Calculates n<sup>2</sup> - n.

Why?  Well we know

```
{({})({}[()])}{}
```

Calculates n<sup>2</sup> and loops n times. That means if we switch the order of the two pushes we go from increasing the sum by n + (n-1) each time to increasing the sum by (n-1) + (n-1) each time. This will decrease the result by one per loop, thus making our result n<sup>2</sup> - n.  At the top level this -n cancels with the n generated by the push that we were zeroing alleviating the need for a zeroer and saving us two bytes.

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 36 bytes

```
({({})(({}[()])){({})({}[()])}{}}{})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6Nao7pWUwNIRGtoxmpqQrhQXm11LRBp/v9vCgA)

Here is another solution, its not as golfy but it's pretty strange so I thought I would leave it as a challenge to figure out how it works.

If you are not into Brain-Flak but you still want the challenge here it is as a summation.

[image: Picture]

---

<sup>1: I came up with my solution before I looked at the answers here. So no plagiarism here.</sup>

Comment: I knew there had to be a way to do this, and I had a feeling you would be the one to figure out the math for it.

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 3 bytes

```
ṁ□ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxkfTFj7csfj///@mAA)

Answer (score 4):

### [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 23 bytes

```
?'+)=:!@/*"*'6/{=+'+}/{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/99eXVvT1krRQV9LSUvdTL/aVltdu1a/@v9/03/5BSWZ@XnF/wE)

#### Explanation

Unfolded:

```
   ? ' + )
  = : ! @ /
 * " * ' 6 /
{ = + ' + } /
 { . . . . .
  . . . . .
   . . . .
```

This is really just a linear program with the `/` used for some redirection. The linear code is:

```
?'+){=+'+}*"*'6{=:!@
```

Which computes **n (n+1) (2n+1) / 6**. It uses the following memory edges:

[image]

Where the memory point (MP) starts on the edge labelled **n**, pointing north.

```
?   Read input into edge labelled 'n'.
'   Move MP backwards onto edge labelled 'n+1'.
+   Copy 'n' into 'n+1'.
)   Increment the value (so that it actually stores the value n+1).
{=  Move MP forwards onto edge labelled 'temp' and turn around to face
    edges 'n' and 'n+1'.
+   Add 'n' and 'n+1' into edge 'temp', so that it stores the value 2n+1.
'   Move MP backwards onto edge labelled '2n+1'.
+   Copy the value 2n+1 into this edge.
}   Move MP forwards onto 'temp' again.
*   Multiply 'n' and 'n+1' into edge 'temp', so that it stores the value
    n(n+1).
"   Move MP backwards onto edge labelled 'product'.
*   Multiply 'temp' and '2n+1' into edge 'product', so that it stores the
    value n(n+1)(2n+1).
'   Move MP backwards onto edge labelled '6'.
6   Store an actual 6 there.
{=  Move MP forwards onto edge labelled 'result' and turn around, so that
    the MP faces edges 'product' and '6'.
:   Divide 'product' by '6' into 'result', so that it stores the value
    n(n+1)(2n+1)/6, i.e. the actual result.
!   Print the result.
@   Terminate the program.
```

In theory it might be possible to fit this program into side-length 3, because the `/` aren't needed for the computation, the `:` can be reused to terminate the program, and some of the `'"=+*{` might be reusable as well, bringing the number of required commands below 19 (the maximum for side-length 3). I doubt it's possible to find such a solution by hand though, if one exists at all.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 3 bytes

```
#²Σ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr/X/nQpnOL//83@Q8A)

**Explanation**

```
#    Range
 ²   Square
  Σ  Sum
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 3 bytes

```
ô²x
```

[Try it here.](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9LJ4&input=NQ==)

-1 thanks to [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy).

Explanation:

```
ò²x 
ô²  Map square on [0..input]
  x Sum
```

Comment: [3 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9bJ4&input=OA==) using the shortcut for `p2`.

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista fixed

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 14 bytes

```
Tr[Range@#^2]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@z@kKDooMS891UE5zihW7X9AUWZeiYK@g0IaiKg20VEwrf3/3wQA)

Comment: `#.#&@Range@#&` saves a byte

Comment: `#.#&@*Range` .

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 46 bytes

```
{(({})[()])}{}{({({})({}[()])}{}<>)<>}<>({{}})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/v1pDo7pWM1pDM1aztrq2WqMaxAVimIiNnaaNHZDUqK6urdX8/98UAA)

Comment: [A little friendly competition :)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145553/57100)

Comment: @Riley Ooh nice :)

Comment: Rather than pushing the square onto the alternate stack, you can sum it directly by evaluating and not pushing it, then pushing the whole loop instead. This changes your second half to `({{({})({}[()])}{}}{})`, and saves you 10 bytes. (If that doesn't make sense, ping me in [the third stack](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41599/the-third-stack))

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>7</s> 5 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to @Mego*

```apl
+.×⍨⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wRtvcPTH/WueNS7GchXOARiGBoAAA)

**How?**

`⍳` - range

`+.×` - dot product

`⍨` - with itself

Comment: @Uriel my bad, i thought the `¨⍳` was necessary

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 10 bytes

```
ri),{_*+}*
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vyhTU6c6Xku7Vuv/fxMA)

```
ri            e# Input integer n
  )           e# Add 1
   ,          e# Range [0 1 ... n]
    {   }*    e# Fold (reduce)
     _        e# Duplicate
      *       e# Multiply
       +      e# Add
```

Comment: How about `ri),_.*:+` or `ri),2f#:+`?

Comment: @Martin Good idea! I think you should post it as a different answer

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), <s>16</s> 14 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to @MartinEnder*

```julia
!n=(x=1:n)⋅x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0/f9fMc9Wo8LW0CpP81F3a8X/tPwihUwFWwVDK0MDLs6Cosy8kpw8DcVMTa7UvJT/AA)

**How?**

`(x=1:n)` creates a range of `1` to `n` and assign to `x`,  `⋅` dot product with `x`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
⟦^₂ᵐ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//9H8ZXGPmpoebp2g/f@/6f8oAA)

#### Explanation

```
⟦        Range
 ^₂ᵐ     Map square
    +    Sum
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 3 bytes

```
R;*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/z/IWuv/fxMA)

Takes `N` as input, and outputs the `N`th element in the sequence.

Explanation:

```
R;*
R    range(1, N+1) ([1, 2, ..., N])
 ;*  dot product with self
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 16 bytes

```
&::2*1+*\1+*6/.@
```

Using the closed-form formula **n*(n+1)*(2n+1)/6**.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X83KykjLUFsrBojN9PUc/v83AQA)

## [Befunge](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 38 bytes

```
v>::*\1-:v0+_$.@
&^ <     _\:^
>:#^_.@
```

Using a loop.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/v8zOykorxlDXqsxAO15Fz4FLLU7BRgEE4mOs4rjsrJTj4vUc/v83BQA)

Answer (score 2):

### R, 17 bytes

```
sum((0:scan())^2)
```

Pretty straightforward, it takes advantage from the fact that `^` (exponentiation) is vectorized in **R**.

Comment: `(x=0:scan())%*%x` is shorter by a byte, but I believe you need a `cat` to get output.

Comment: @Giuseppe I've just tried it and your code works without `cat`, it outputs a 1x1 matrix.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Current meta consensus is that `cat` is necessary for this to qualify as a full program. If you wish to change that, answer [this question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13743/how-should-a-full-program-in-r-be-invoked) and get some traction among the other R people on the site.

Answer (score 2):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 9 bytes

```
ri),_.*:+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vyhTUydeT8tK@/9/EwA)

#### Explanation

```
ri        e# Read input and convert to integer N.
  ),      e# Get range [0 1 2 ... N].
    _     e# Duplicate.
     .*   e# Pairwise products, giving [0 1 4 ... N^2].
       :+ e# Sum.
```

Alternatively:

```
ri),2f#:+
```

This squares each element by mapping `2#` instead of using pairwise products. And just for fun another alternative which gets inaccurate for large inputs because it uses floating-point arithmetic:

```
ri),:mh2#
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 15 bytes

```
Iu):^\+*p*6u@O,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/9@zVNMqLkZbq0DLrNTBX@f/f1MA)

My code is a bit sad `):`

Computes `n*(n+1)*(2n+1)/6`

```
    I u
    ) :
^ \ + * p * 6 u
@ O , . . . . .
    . .
    . .
```

```
^Iu : read in input, u-turn
    : stack  n
:)\ : dup, increment, go right..oh, hey, it cheered up!
    : stack: n, n+1
+   : sum
    : stack: n, n+1, 2*n+1
*   : multiply
    : stack: n, n+1, 2*n+1, (n+1)*(2*n+1)
p   : move bottom of stack to top
    : stack: n+1, 2*n+1, (n+1)*(2*n+1), n
*   : multiply
6   : push 6
u   : right u-turn
,   : divide
O   : output
@   : terminate
```

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>15</s> <s>13</s> 11 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to *Not a tree*

```
0:n:l1-:*+!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38AqzyrHUNdKS1vx/38A)

Outputs the sequence indefinitely.

Comment: 14 bytes (12+2 for `-v` flag): `::1+:}+**6,n` ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38rKUNuqVltLy0wn7////7plFgA "><> – Try It Online"))

Comment: Or 11 bytes (prints forever, starting at `N=1`): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3yCGy8oux0pL2yrv/38A "><> – Try It Online")

Comment: @Notatree: Very nice idea using `l`. Checking with OP if it is okay to start at 1.

Comment: @Notatree: Unfortunately we aren't allowed to start at 1, but it still saves 2 bytes. Thanks!

Comment: (I should mention that I got the `l` idea from Martin Ender's [Labyrinth answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145571/66104).)

Answer (score 2):

### [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 11 bytes

```
:!\
+ :
*:#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/fSjGGS1vBikvLSvn/f1MA)

Prints the sequence indefinitely.

#### Explanation

The instruction pointer just keeps running around the square of code over and over:

```
:!\    Duplicate the last result (initially zero), print it and a linefeed.
:      Duplicate the result again, which increases the stack depth.
#      Push the stack depth (used as a counter variable).
:*     Square it.
+      Add it to the running total.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <strike>7</strike> 5 bytes thanks to Steven H

```
s^R2h
```

Explanation:

```
s^R2h       Full program - inputs from stdin and outputs to stdout
s           output the sum of
    h       range(input), with
 ^R2         each element squared
```

---

My first solution

```
sm*ddUh
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/vzhXKyUl@P9/cwA)

Explanation:

```
sm*ddUh    Full program - inputs from stdin and outputs to stdout
s          sum of
 m   Uh    each d in range(input)
  *dd      squared
```

Comment: Is there no square built in in Pyth?

Comment: Not as far as I know...

Comment: No there is no square built-in Pyth. Also [6 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v1grLDgw@P9/cwA)

Comment: [5 bytes](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%5ER2S&input=5&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A11%0A12%0A13%0A14%0A15%0A16%0A17%0A18%0A19%0A20%0A21%0A22%0A23%0A24&debug=0).

Comment: Fixable with +1 byte to each answer, I'll edit once I get off of mobile.

Comment: Five bytes solution works with versions of the Pyth compiler before [this commit.](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth/commit/c374b45f059646503bc426ff0cb47fe567f0514a)  It's just a bit harder to show off with an online compiler, seeing as all of those have gotten updated since mid-May.

Comment: For an alternate five-bytes solution, `s^R2h` works.  Numbers are turned into ranges with `U` automatically when mapped.

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 20 bytes

```
f 0=0
f n=n*n+f(n-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P03BwNaAK00hzzZPK087TSNP11Dzf25iZp6CrUJBUWZeiYKKQpqC6X8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
4%~3!2*>:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegnqZga6WgrqCjYKBgBcS6egrOQT5u/01U64wVjbTsrP5rcnGlJmfkK6QpmMAYpv8B)

*Saved 1 byte using an explicit formula, thanks to miles!*

---

### J, 10 bytes

```
1#.]*:@-i.
```

J has a range function, but this gives us number from `0` to `N-1`. To remedy this, we can just take the argument and subtract the range from it, giving us a range from `N` to `1`. This is done with `]   -i.`. The rest of the code simply square this list argument (`*:@`) and then sums it (`1#.`).

### Other contenders

**11 bytes**: `1#.*:@i.@>:`

**13 bytes**: `1#.[:,@:*/~i.`

Comment: ``4%~3!2*>:`` saves a byte

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 19 bytes

```
=A1^3/3+A1^2/2+A1/6
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
R²
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UrBS7IKlpSVpuhaLgw5tWlKclFwM5S9YaAJhAAA)

##### Explanation

```python
R²  # Implicit input
R   # Range of input
 ²  # Square each
    # Sum the list
    # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 3 bytes

```
R:∙
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FkuDrB51zFxSnJRcDBVZsNSAy4TLFMIBAA)

```
R:∙
R     Range
 :    Duplicate
  ∙   Dot product
```

Because there isn't a square built-in yet.

Answer (score 1):

## [Oasis](https://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis), 4 bytes

```
nk+0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08sziz@/z8vW9vg////JgA)

**Explanation**

```
   0      # a(0) = 0
nk+       # a(n) = a(n-1)+n^2
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 3 bytes

```
ᛦ
```

This could've been a challenge to show off Neim's polygonal number builtins, but apparently not.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//8PcCR0PZy8DUmv@/zcFAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 3 bytes

```
s¦Σ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/v/jQsnOL//83BQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 18 bytes

```ruby
->n{n*~n*~(n+n)/6}
```

Using the sama formula as everybody else, saved 1 byte with a double negative multiplication.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOk@rDog08rTzNPXNav8XlJYUK6RFm8b@BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, <s>24</s>, 21 bytes

Thanks to Dom, solutions with 21 bytes

```
$\+=$_--**2while$_}{
```

or

```
map$\+=$_**2,1..$_}{
```

or

```
$\+=$_**2for 1..$_}{
```

previous were 21 + 1 `-p` flag, 3 bytes saved thanks to Xcali

```
$_*=($_+1)*(2*$_+1)/6
```

and 23 +1

```
$_=$_*($_+1)*(2*$_+1)/6
```

or

```
$_=$_**3/3+$_**2/2+$_/6
```

Comment: You can shorten this by factoring out the $_ and replacing `=` with `*=`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXssWiLWM9I21VeL1jbQN9c3@/zf9l19QkpmfV/xftwAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: This looks to be 22 bytes (21 + 1 for `-p`)... But here's one for 21 bytes using a different approach entirely: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lRttWJV5Lyygtv0jBUE9PJb62@v9/03/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: good point, there is also `$\+=$_--**2while$_}{`

Answer (score 1):

## awk, 25 bytes

```
{print$1^3/3+$1^2/2+$1/6}
```

Answer (score 1):

## dc, <s>15</s> 12 bytes

```dc
d1+dd+1-**6/
```

This is simply the factorised Faulhaber polynomial: n(n+1)(2n+1)/6, except that the (2n+1) term is calculated as 2(n+1)-1.

Answer (score 1):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), <s>33</s> <s>24</s> 19 bytes

*-9 bytes thanks to [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis)*

*-5 bytes thanks to [ASCII-only](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39244/ascii-only) and bugfixes.*

```
f=n=>n?f(n-1)+n*n:0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvNy678X1CUmVeiofE/zTbP1i7PPk0jT9dQUztPK8/K4L@mhomm5n8A)

Comment: [26 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyvNy678n2b7P8/Wrjotv0gj39bAOs9aM982XztPK09XN7/2f0FRZl6JRpqGiabmfwA "Funky – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 28 bytes

```
&00pg#v_.@
-1:g00<^g00+*:p00
```

Works for inputs in the range [0, 128). Due to befunge being entirely stack-based, and yet having limited stack manipulation operations available, the only way to work with three values (sum, partial sum, and counter) is to store a value temporarily by modifying the program itself using the `p` instruction. Since `p` assigns a value as ASCII, the stored value wraps around at 128, storing a negative value instead of a positive value.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X83AoCBduSxez4FL19Aq3cDAJg5IaGtZFRgY/P9vaAAA)

## [Befunge](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 30 bytes

```
& >::*\:v
$<^-1_v#<@.
_^#:\+<\
```

Works for pretty much any input.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X03BzspKK8aqjEvFJk7XML5M2cZBjys@TtkqRtsm5v9/UwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>38</s> 33  bytes

-5 bytes thanks to [Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender)

```
g=lambda x:x*x+g(x-1) if x else 0
```

Haven't seen any solution with recursion yet, so I thought I'd post this one. It may not be really competitive, but this is my first time posting.

**Edit:** It would've been -11 bytes thanks to [Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender), but I would've ended up with the same answer as  [Mr. Xcoder's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145519/75708)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Here are a few ideas: `x**2` is `x*x`, you can avoid the parentheses if you just put the condition on top and avoid the `<1` if you switch the true and false branches (because `0` is falsy). However, `y if x else 0` can be expressed more concisely as `x and y`, due to the short-circuiting behaviour of `and`. So you end up with `g=lambda x:x and x*x+g(x-1)`. :)

Comment: @Martin Ender  Thank you for the tips. I am going to simplify the **2 and the <1, but I won't replace the ternary operator with the "and" statement, since it will be the same as Mr. Xcoder's second answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
Rḋ`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/o4Y7uhP///5sAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Flurry](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flurry), 30 bytes

```
{}{({})[<><<>()>]<[][]>}[<>()]
```

#### Run example

```
$ ./flurry -nin -c "{}{({})[<><<>()>]<[][]>}[<>()]" 0
0
$ ./flurry -nin -c "{}{({})[<><<>()>]<[][]>}[<>()]" 1
1
$ ./flurry -nin -c "{}{({})[<><<>()>]<[][]>}[<>()]" 3
14
$ ./flurry -nin -c "{}{({})[<><<>()>]<[][]>}[<>()]" 6
91
```

The computation is done via the stack, but the final result is outputted from the return value.

Given that we can keep track of iteration indexes using the stack height and multiplication is cheap in Flurry, there's really no "clever" alternative that can lead to shorter code.

```
{}{...}[<>()]  Repeat the lambda n times with the start value of zero
                 (implicit) push argument x to the stack
  ({})           Pop and re-push x; return x
  [<><<>()>]     succ
  <[][]>         (height ∘ height)
                 In effect, push x and return x + height^2
```

Comment: "succ" hmmm....

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
ɾ²∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiyb7CsuKIkSIsIiIsIjRcbjUiXQ==)

#### Explained

```
ɾ²∑
ɾ   # range 1 inclusive [1...n]
 ²  # square
  ∑ # sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 3 bytes

```
ř²Ʃ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//6MxDm46t/P/f0AAA)

```
ř²Ʃ
       implicit input
ř      creates array of 1 to n
 ²     squares each element
  Ʃ    sums the list
       implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 19 bytes

```arturo
$=>[∑map&=>[&^2]]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?plBpTt)

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 16 bytes

```
[\+] {$++²}...*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1up4FCsYPs/OkY7VqFaRVv70KZaPT09rf/WCsWJILnoOEOD2P8A)

This is an expression for the lazy infinite sequence of numbers.

- `{ $++² } ... *` is the infinite sequence of square numbers.  `$` is an anonymous state variable whose postincremented value is squared to obtain each new element.
- `[\+]` is the sequence of partial sums of that sequence.

Answer (score 0):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 16 bytes

```
x=>x*(x+++x)*x/6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@59m@7/C1q5CS6NCW1u7QlOrQt/sf0FRZl6JRpqGqabm//8A)

Straightforward Solution: `range+map(x=>x**2)+sum`

-2 bytes thanks to Arnauld('s answer)

Answer (score 0):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 13 bytes

```
[:|p=p+a^2]?p
```

### Explanation

```
[:|    FOR a = 1 to <input from cmd line>
p=p+   increment p by
a^2    a squared
]      NEXT
?p     PRINT p
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>78</s> <s>57</s> <s>35</s> 16 bytes

@Arnauld port

```
i->i*(i+++i)*i/6
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 4 bytes

```
hLXs
```

[Try it here!](https://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=hLXs&input=5&warnings=0&hex=0)

**or...**

```
SMXs
```

Answer (score 0):

## [4](https://github.com/urielieli/py-four), 39 bytes

```
3.7006110180020100000030301100001195034
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hca5EQAgEMPAmGJgZI63Mdo3DNpEzY4yYUhoQUX84tF/aXei2cn5XA)

**How?**

```
3.
7 00        grid[0] = input()
6 11 01     grid[11] = 1
8 00        while grid[0] != 0:
2 01 00 00     grid[1] = grid[0] * grid[0]
0 03 03 01     grid[3] = grid[3] + grid[1]
1 00 00 11     grid[0] = grid[0] - grid[11]
9         
5 03        print(grid[3]) 
4
```

Answer (score 0):

## Octave, 14 bytes

```matlab
@(k)(a=0:k)*a'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNbUyPR1sAqW1MrUf1/Yl6xhonmfwA)

*Dot product.

Or

```matlab
@(k)sumsq(0:k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNbs7g0t7hQw8AqW/N/Yl6xhonmfwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 21 bytes

```hs
f n=n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzzZPSyNP21BTS8NIC0Trm/3PTczMsy0oyswrUVBRSFMw@Q8A)

Boring, straightforward implementation of the closed-form formula on the OEIS page. Expanding into polynomial form doesn't save any bytes: `f n=(2*n^3+3*n^2+n)/6`.

Comment: Same byte count: `f n=sum$map(^2)[1..n]`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 36 bytes

```
proc S n {expr $n*($n+1)*(2*$n+1)/6}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WSFYIU@hOrWioEhBJU9LQyVP21BTS8NIC8zQN6v9X1BaUqwQHaxgEssFY5rG/gcA)

Comment: Longer approach, that does not work well with zero: https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WSFYIU@hujwjMydVIUYFyMzMSy5SKFaITq0oKFJQydNSyYu1BovlKega1loXp5YoFNf@LygtAaoJVjCJ5YIxTWO5lGFsg9j/AA

Comment: Another longer approach, that does not work well with zero: https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WSFYIU@huiQzN1WhOjMvuUihWCE6taKgSCEazMuM1VLJjK1VUMmzLk4tUSiu/V9QWgJUEqxgEssFY5rGcinD2Aax/wE

Comment: Yet another longer approach, that does not work well with zero: https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WSFYIU@huiQzN1WhOrGgIDUvRaFYQTs6My@5SCEzVksls1ZBJc86taKgSEGluPZ/QWlJsUJ0sIJJLBeMaRrLpQxjG8T@BwA

Comment: The same approach as the Javascript answer has one byte more: https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WSFYIU@hOrWioEhBJU9LQyVPOzozL7lIIS9WU0slT9@s9n9BaUmxQnSwgkksF4xpGvsfAA Tks, @Arnauld

Answer (score 0):

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

*-1 bytes thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder)*

```lua
n*~n*~(n+n)/6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/z9Pqw6INPK08zT1zf7//28CAA)

Comment: [13 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/z9Pqw6INPK08zT1zf7//28CAA)

Answer (score 0):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), <s>17</s> 12 bytes

```
./ O \d2E+.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/19PX8FfISbFyFVbj@v/fwA)

Prints the sequence indefinitely.

The trailing linefeed is significant.

#### Explanation

```
.   Duplicate the current total. Initially this pushes two zeros onto the
    previously empty stack.
/   Switch to Ordinal.
O   Print the current total with a trailing linefeed.
\   Switch back to Cardinal.
d   Push the stack depth, which acts as a counter variable.
2E  Square it.
+   Add it to the current total.
.   Duplicate it to increment the stack depth for the next iteration.
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 20 bytes

```
.+
$*
M!&`.+
1
$%_
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0@bS0WLy1dRLQHIMuRSUY3nMvz/3wDINOIy5jLhMgUA)

#### Explanation

```
.+
$*
```

Convert input to unary.

```
M!&`.+
```

Get all overlapping matches of `.+` which turns the input into a range of unary numbers from **1** to **n**.

```
1
$%_
```

Replace each `1` with the entire line its on, squaring the unary value on each line.

```
1
```

Count the number of `1`s, summing all lines and converting them back to decimal.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 16 bytes

```
n->(v=[0..n])*v~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9P106jzDbaQE8vL1ZTq6zuf0FRZl6JRpqGiabmfwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [cQuents 0](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents/tree/cquents-0), 3 bytes

```
;$$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/31pF5f9/UwA)

Take that, Oasis.

### Explanation

```
;     Mode: Sum - given n, output the sum of the sequence up to n
 $$   Each term in the sequence equals the index * the index
```

Comment: does not work for input `0`

Answer (score 0):

## [Recursiva](https://github.com/officialaimm/recursiva), 8 bytes

```
smBa'Sa'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pNLi0qzixL/P@/ONcpUT04Uf3/f1MA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>48</s> 30 bytes

```bash
echo "$1*($1+1)*(2*$1+1)/6"|bc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BScVQS0PFUNtQU0vDSAvM0DdTqklK/v//vwkA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 10 bytes

```
VhQ=+Z^N2Z
```

Outputs the first N elements of the sequence.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Pywj0FY7Ks7PKOr/f1MA)

---

How?

```
VhQ=+Z^N2Z              Full program

VhQ                     Loop until Q + 1 is reached
   =+Z                  Assign and increment Z by ...
      ^N2               ... N squared
         Z              Implicity prints Z
```

---

11 byte alternative.

```
VhQ aY^N2sY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PywjUCExMs7PqDjy/39TAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 6 bytes

```
R2KeS#
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/z/IyDs1WPn///8mAA)

#### Explanation

```
R     Push integers from 1 to implicit n, where n is implicit input
2     Push 2
K     Next command will use the entire stack
e     Pop 2. Raise each of the remaing stack entries to that
S     Sum the entire stack
#     Print as integer
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 20 bytes

```
[range(.+1)|.*.]|add
```

Input is `N`. Output is `N`'th element of sequence.  Expanded:

```
[
    range(.+1)            # generate series 0, 1, 2, 3, ... N
  | .*.                   # square each term
]                         # collect into an array
| add                     # compute the sum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8b1rzP7ooMS89VUNP21CzRk9LL7YmMSXl//9/@QUlmfl5xf91dfNKc3J0M/MKSkuAnKLEct380hIgBwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 9 bytes

**Solution:**

```
+/x*x:!1+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X1u/QqvCStFQ2@T/fwA)

**Examples:**

```
> +/x*x:!1+4
30
> +/x*x:!1+5
55
```

**Explanation:**

Evaluated right-to-left:

```
+/x*x:!1+ / solution
       1+ / add 1 to input, 1+4 => 5
      !   / til, !5 => 0 1 2 3 4
    x:    / save as variable x
  x*      / vectorised multiplication, x*x, 0 1 2 3 4*0 1 2 3 4 => 0 1 3 9 16
+/        / addition over (sum), +/0 1 3 9 16 => 30
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C#(.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 20 bytes

```
a=>a*(a+1)*(2*a+1)/6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYw9C8IwFEX3/Io7Jn5UFHGp7VJw0snB@RkzPGgT6UsFKf3tMUKGe7hnOVa2Nowuvadnzxa2JxF0s5JIMfv9K9EN1WXy9sw@bvJacJMITQvCCpqwxt783yGj2A6nVKvSLKlP4BduxF4bNZduF7yE3lWPkaO7snea9dGYWi1qST8)

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 16 bytes

```r
(n=0:scan())%*%n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/XyPP1sCqODkxT0NTU1VLNe@/6X8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [TacO](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/TacO), 10 bytes

```
@i i
+%+*i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0lMzv//3yFTIZNLW1VbK/P///8mAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Threead](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Threead), 40 bytes

```
I[     -]_
   _^>1
  _2 _r

[<

 lo
 ]
+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8koSk1NTPn/3zNaAQR0Y@O5gFR8nJ0hkI43Uogv4uKKtuHiUsjJ51KI5dL@/98EAA)

### De-sliced

This is actually 4 bytes larger, due to whitespace.

```
I[     -]_   lo
   _^>1   [< ]
  _2 _r     +
```

### Process.

1. Read an integer into the first value
2. While the first value is non-zero.

   1. Blank the third value, push 2 onto it.
   2. Blank the second value, then calculate the first value to the power of the third, (i^2)
   3. Move the second value to the right and place a 1 onto it.
   4. Put the value of the first value onto the third value.
   5. Calculate the third value minus the second value (i-1)
3. Now the second tape contains the squares of all numbers from inp to 1 squared.
4. Blank the first value
5. While the second value is non-zero

   1. Move the second tape to the left.
   2. Add the first value to the second value into the third value.
   3. Move the third value into the first value
6. Now, all the i^2 values are summed together, output the first value.

Answer (score 0):

## [ReRegex](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ReRegex), 53 bytes

```
#import math
^k([1-9]\d*)/k($1-1)+$1*$1/k0+/0/k#input
```

### Explained

```
#import math                # Import the math library.
^k([1-9]\d*)/k($1-1)+$1*$1/ # Search the buffer for "k" followed by a non-zero number. Replace it with "k<n-1>+n*n"
k0+/0/                      # Replace k0 with just 0
k#input                     # Default the buffer to k<input>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otSk1Prfj/XzkztyC/qEQhN7EkgysuWyPaUNcyNiZFS1M/W0PFUNdQU1vFUEvFUD/bQFvfQD9bOTOvoLTk/38TAA)

Answer (score 0):

### TI-BASIC, 10 bytes

```
sum(seq(X²,X,0,Ans
```

Quite simple. The sum of the sequence of the first `Ans` squares.

Answer (score 0):

## [MaybeLater](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/MaybeLater), 36 bytes

```
n=(readn)/1
write(n*(n+1)*(1+n*2)/6)
```

Using the closed form formula.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y02sTErNSSxJLfr/P89Woyg1MSVPU9@Qq7wosyRVI09LI0/bUFNLw1A7T8tIU99M8/9/EwA)

Comment: Surely you could have posted two different approaches in the same answer?

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 30 bytes

```
(loop as i to(read)sum(* i i))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74r1FQlJlX8l8jJz@/QCGxWCFToSRfoyg1MUWzuDRXQwvIz9TU/K/53xQA)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 18 bytes

```js
f=n=>n&&n*n--+f(n)
```

---

### Try it

```js
o.innerText=(
f=n=>n&&n*n--+f(n)
)(i.value=8);oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(+i.value)
```

```html
<input id=i type=number><pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic, 10 bytes

```
sum(seq(OO,O,0,Ans
```

sp00ky

Answer (score 0):

## [Milky Way](https://github.com/zachgates/Milky-Way), 10 bytes

```
'L§{:*}G!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y83Mya7ULU@s/P9f3efQ8morrVp3xf///@tmKpgCAA)

### Explanation:

```
'          push input to stack
 L         push inclusive range
  ${  }    map over every element ...
    :*     ... duplicate and multiply (square it)
       G   sum of list
        !  output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/SatansSon/AddPlusPlus), 13 bytes

```
D,f,@,RdBcB*s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ03HQScoxSnZSav4////pgA)

```
D,f,@,   - Create a monadic function called f. Argument n (example: 5)
      R  - Generate range;   STACK = [[1 2 3 4 5]]
      d  - Duplicate;        STACK = [[1 2 3 4 5] [1 2 3 4 5]]
      Bc - Push the columns; STACK = [[1 1] [2 2] [3 3] [4 4] [5 5]]
      B* - Product of each;  STACK = [1 4 9 16 25]
      s  - Push the sum;     STACK = [1 4 9 16 25 55]
         - Implicitly return 55
```

Answer (score -1):

## Postscript, 149 bytes

```
/d {def}def
/a {
0 i l 1 0 l
i 2 ge {/i i 1 sub d a}if
} d
/l {rlineto}d
/m {moveto}d
/b {/j exch d /i j d 0 0 m j a j 0 lineto closepath fill}d
5 b
```